# Issue with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

**In ViewController A:**

```
// ViewDidLoad

self.theArray = // set up my array here with objects

// TableView

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.viewControllerTwo = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.myString = [self.theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.myString forKey:@"stringKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewControllerTwo animated:YES];
}
```

**In ViewController B:**

```
// ViewDidLoad

self.aLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"stringKey"];
```

In my View Controller A, where I am setting the string in `NSUserDefaults`, I can see that it is matching with the cell I tap on, but when I push to View Controller B, my label is not picking up what is stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I changed it to this:

```
// In FirstViewController

self.viewControllerTwo = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

self.myString = [self.theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

self.viewControllerTwo.secondString = self.myString;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewControllerTwo animated:YES];

// In SecondViewController

self.aLabel.text = self.secondString;
```

Comment: try to display in NSLog and see if it comes in log or not.it it comes then there is problem in the label not in userdefaults

Comment: I did. I just got it working. Instead of using NSUserDefaults, I just set a string in my SecondViewController to match the string in my FirstViewController, then set the label text to the string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1、Make sure the string is valid which means it is neither @"" nor "white characters".

2、Make sure the self.aLabel is added to your base view and self.aLabel is not nil.

Comment: The string is valid, it's getting the value I set. The self.aLabel comes back as (null) though

Comment: @LukeIrvin So that's the problem.